# Best practice for overloading functions with only STL types

Tags: c++, stl, argument-dependent-lookup

I would like to overload `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::chrono::duration<std::uint64, std::nano>)` - and ideally without requiring users to write `using` statements everywhere.

What's the best practice here?

---

Context...

```
// Replace code like this:
using Time = std::uint64_t;
void example(Time ts) {
    if (ts) { std::cout << ts; }

}

// with code like this:
using Time = std::chrono::duration<std::uint64_t, std::nano>;
void example(Time ts) {
    if (!!ts) { std::cout << ts; }
}

// this 'works for me'; but it is not allowed to add overloads to `namespace std`
// The type `Time` can be used in any other namespace, and the operators are found by ADL
namespace std {
    ostream& operator<<(ostream&, chrono::duration<uint64_t, nano>);
    bool operator!(chrono::duration<uint64_t, nano>);
}
```

Is there a way to get the effect of placing the overloads in the `std` namespace without breaking the rules on extending `namespace std`?

Comment: You can not add user defined types or function in std namespace. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std says its undefined behavior.

Comment: Do your overloads need to be in a namespace at all? If so, why? Or why not a namespace you have made that also include the `Time` type?

Comment: Create a namespace that contains your `Time` type, and place the overload of `operator<<()` in that namespace.   Refer to `std::ostream` and other types in `std` via their fully qualified names.   One consequence will be that `some_stream << some_time` will be resolved if `some_time` is an instance of your `namespace::Time` type, but not be resolved for an instance of `std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, nano>`.  That is actually a benefit, for example, if you need to change what the `Time` type is.

Comment: Those suggestions don't work, because `Time` is just an alias for `std::chrono::duration`. This is the problem at the heart of the question; how do you overload a function that takes only STL types, make it conveniently available via ADL and not break to the rule about adding to `namespace std`.

Comment: @Zero - The point is that you shouldn't place anything into `std` (except in very specific circumstances, allowed by the standard) - and that includes what you are doing.  Placing `Time` and the operators you want to overload into a separate namespace does address your concern - that allows overloading for your `Time` even it is an alias for a type in `std`, but the overload will not be called with an argument that is created directly as a type in `std` (i.e. the compiler doesn't go *that* far in resolving calls).

Comment: I think the closest is @Peter, requires users add `using my_namespace::operator<<;` or similar in each user namespace.  https://godbolt.org/z/41f6jxsM7

I know you can't add to `std` - it's written in the question "it is not allowed to add overloads to `namespace std`".

Comment: overload with types you don't own (as std ones) is dangerous: not in your namespace scope, it might introduce ODR violation if someone does the same choice/mistake. Wrap the type entirely and/or just provide overload in your namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put it in the global namespace. Any function outside of `namespace std` that does name lookup for `<<` will find your overload, and prefer it to the [one defined in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_ltlt).

Afaict, the only place where this fails is `std::ostream_iterator`, as that is the only call to `<<` within `namespace std`.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f153d8950b81b7a6)